# LINQ Grouping a List of Objects into Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having difficulty trying to use LINQ to query a sql database in such a way to group all objects (b) in one table associated with an object (a) in another table into an anonymous type with both (a) and a list of (b)s. Essentially, I have a database with a table of offers, and another table with histories of actions taken related to those offers. What I'd like to be able to do is group them in such a way that I have a list of an anonymous type that contains every offer, and a list of every action taken on that offer, so the signature would be:

`List<'a>`
where `'a is new { Offer offer, List<OfferHistories> offerHistories}`

Here is what I tried initially, which obviously will not work

```
var query = (from offer in context.Offers
             join offerHistory in context.OffersHistories on offer.TransactionId equals offerHistory.TransactionId
             group offerHistory by offerHistory.TransactionId into offerHistories
             select { offer, offerHistories.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Normally I wouldn't come to SE with this little information but I have tried many different ways and am at a loss for how to proceed.

Comment: Instead of `group` you should be using `GroupJoin` - put an `into` after `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to avoid `.ToList()` calls, only do if really necessary. I have an important question: Do you really need all columns of OffersHistories? Because it is very expensive grouping a full object, try only grouping the necessary columns instead. If you really need all offerHistories for one offer then I'm suggesting to write a sub select (this is also cost more performance):

```
var query = (from offer in context.Offers
             select new { offer, offerHistories = (from offerHistory in context.OffersHistories
                                                   where offerHistory.TransactionId == offer.TransactionId
                                                   select offerHistory) });
```

P.s.: it's a good idea to create indexes for foreign key columns, columns that are used in where and group by statements, those are going to make the query faster,